# Problems with Retrofit2 - Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I can't retrieve data when json data look like this :

```
{
"": "",
"": ""
}
```

But everything work like this :

```
[
{
"": "",
"": ""
}
]
```

My problem is I really need to retrieve my data like the first option.

```
public interface API {
    String BASE_URL = "https://cloud-functions-d378b.firebaseapp.com/";

    @GET("PLAYER_API.json")
    Call<List<Players>> getPlayer();
}


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_info);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
                .build();


        API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

        Call<List<Players>> call = api.getPlayer();

        onResponse will be executed

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Players>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Players>> call, Response<List<Players>> response) {


                List<Players> playersList = response.body();


                String[] players = new String[playersList.size()];


                for (int i = 0; i < playersList.size(); i++) {
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve my data with this format:

```
{
"": "",
"": ""
}
```

Comment: Are you demonstrating the format of the response or is it actually coming back with empty strings as key/values?

Comment: But do you want a list? maybe you only need to change your object, if the API returns a list, there not much you can do, it's not going to work otherwise, what do you need the list to be like that? you maybe want a FlatMap

Comment: @EdGeorge This is my response!

Comment: My response look like this { "id": 8256545, "name": "Alexandre"}

Answer (score 1):

Just change declaration of api call:

```
Call<Players> getPlayer();
```